# Using something like timeEvent and currentTime, can I change a css element while an mp3 file is playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Basically, I'm making a glorified online powerpoint: an mp3 player in a fullscreen div (html5 audio element). I have a lecture on mp3, I want the background and text to change when we hit certain parts in the lecture. So my theory is I can change the id or class of the div when we get to certain timeEvents (changing the background of div and hiding or revealing certain text). Which sounds nice in theory, but in practice looks like a pig trying to code javascript with its snout. Yelp.

```
var aud = document.getElementById("lecture1");

aud.ontimeupdate = function () myFunction() {
 if (aud.currentTime >= 0 && aud.currentTime < 5) {
   document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('pictures/first.jpg')";
 }
 if (aud.currentTime >= 5 && aud.currentTime < 10) {
    document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url('pictures/second.jpg')";
 }
```

Comment: show your code, and be specific about what is not working

Comment: No, put code in question and highlight it.  then press {} button on the edit menu

Comment: Sorry, Joel, I'm new to this.

Comment: So during the first 5 seconds do you see first.jpg? after that do you see second.jpg?  Also your function() myFunction looks wrong.  Check syntax -- I don't think you need the () after function

Comment: I see nothing and my console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
16test.html:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"

Comment: remove myfunction ().  You are defining the function twice, and you arent returning anything to aud.ontimeupdate

Comment: I did, but nothing has really changed. Joel, you can see it at: http://sam.alcoff.com/podcasttest/test.html (obviously just random media in there at the moment)